# Creating button dynamically

Tags: android, widget

hey guys need a little help........my intention is to develop an app which contains just a button... and on clicking it it must create another button on the screen dynamically.......

here's my code...

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Button bee=new Button(getBaseContext());
            bee.setText("hello:");
             RelativeLayout a;
            a=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    a.addView(bee,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    });
```

this code is error free but when executed says "unfortunately 'myapplication' has stopped"....

pls do help guys..( my sole aim is to create widgets dynamically ,hence tried dis program). if u have any other suggestions pls post nd comment

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look at the stacktrace in the logcat and post it in your question.

Comment: Check `logcat` for the reason for your application crashing.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.. Please note these things 1)When you post a question, please make sure its title is valid. android developer (beginer) is not one. 2) If you get crash, most important thing you need to post is crash log

Answer (score 1):

```
 a=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

activity_main is a layout, not a RelativeLayout widget!

you should use

```
 a=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);
```

Please post the stack trace (logcat) so you will get better and faster answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to "find" a layout which can't exist! Please, make sure you have defined a `RealtiveLayout` with a valid id and then do

`a=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.valid_layout_id);`

instead of

`a=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); // Here this should be id of your relative layout.
Button btn = new Button(this);
rLayout.addView(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are finding id rather then layout

so change this line:

```
a=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code i think you are getting problem just because of not setting the parameters properly so check with this code-

```
 LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn.setLayoutParams(lp);

    container.addView(btn);
```